# Create graph using animation nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

How to Create graph like this using animation nodes?

It should be X,Y values animateable

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far and what does and does not work?

Comment: still trying to figure out how to add numbers to x and y

https://imgur.com/oDT01DQ